# Cmd + z doesn't shut down python

Tags: python, macos

I try to run a python program on my mac terminal. I want to manually terminate it by pressing "cmd + z". I openup "monitor", and I still see python-2.7 getting 8GB ram (wtf?), and using some cpu resources. How do I completely shut down this python program (I can't force quit because I also got another python program running on a different and separate terminal.

---

Just want to clarify my description, I ran two python programs, and in the "monitor", I see two Python-2.7 running.

I want to terminate one of the python program running in my terminal. How do I completely shut down that one (and also free up the resources that it is using).

Comment: If you're sure only one python instance is running, try `killall python`. Also on mac os, use `Ctrl + D` not `cmd + Z`. The latter only puts the current process into background.

Answer (score 0):

cmd + Z puts the currently-running process into the background. Ctrl+D will cause Python to exit

You can use kill with the pid of your background process to close it

Comment: you can also type `fg` (ForeGround) to bring the process 'forwards' again

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the PIDS for any jobs with:

```
lsof +D path/folder
```

and then:

```
kill -9 PID-number
```

Also, `ctrl+Z` while the process is running can stop it as well.

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` unless you know for a faot that it's necessary. See also [useless use of `kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill)

Answer (score 0):

You can quit a python program by typing `quit()` without the quotes of course. Be sure to include the parentheses.